# How do I print 95% CI with pairs (emmeans)?

Tags: emmeans

I want to print the difference between groups (control_str2) with emmeans, but pairs only prints mean +/- SE.

`em_means <- emmeans(ComPAS_MUAC115_LinearGrowth_ForAnalysis_completecases_2.1, specs = ~ control_str2, digits=1)

## Calculate pairwise differences between groups

pairwise_diff <- pairs(em_means, conf.level=0.95, digits=1)`

I tried printing this but it doesn't work:
`lower_CI <- pairwise_diff$lower.CL  # Extracting lower CIs
upper_CI <- pairwise_diff$upper.CL  # Extracting upper CIs

## Combine results for easier viewing or further processing

result <- data.frame(lower_CI, upper_CI)  # Creating a data frame with lower and upper CIs
print(result)`

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
CIs <- confint(pairs(em_means))
```

then `CIs` will include confidence limits instead of tests, and will be a data frame instead of an `emmGrid` object.